# WordPress Cookie Redirect - Home Page to Blog Page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies

I'm using WordPress and I want the user to go to the Home Page on their first visit, but on every other visit after that I would like them to be redirected to the Blog.

Home Page:

```
www.website.com
```

Blog:

```
www.website.com/blog
```

I'm guessing the best way to do this is to set a cookie?

I have no idea on what PHP files to edit or anything...

Comment: I think this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943968/apache-rewrite-rules-for-cookies  But it doesn't have an accepted answer.  This is the right idea, though.  You might want to add an Apache tag to your post because I think that's an important piece.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - not a duplicate and not really need  `apache` . simple `php` will do combined with come wordpress conditionals. see my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme functions.php ( or plugin )

```
function o99_set_newvisitor_cookie() {
    if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['sitename_newvisitor'])) {
        setcookie('sitename_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600*24*100, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'o99_set_newvisitor_cookie');
```

After that

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['sitename_newvisitor'])) {
     echo 'Welcome back!'; // or redirect using wp_redirect( 'some_url/' ); exit;
}
else {
     echo 'Hello new visitor!'; // or redirect using wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
}
```

This should do the job .

Wordpress itself had a function called [wp_setcookie()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_setcookie) but it was deprecated and replaced by [wp_set_auth_cookie()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) which is only for user auth I believe . Not sure why, but maybe because of cookies laws that were introduced ( and that also you need to take into account )

Anyhow, see also the normal [PHP setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) docs and the [wp_redierct()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function in codex.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this but I am getting this error: http://prntscr.com/8idq6j  I placed the code in the functions file as advised. Here is the code: http://prntscr.com/8idpvd

Comment: Thanks heaps! It's working but now there is one small issue.. When I'm trying to access the admin area of WordPress is also being redirected as well... Is there a way to stop redirection on the URL www.website.com/wp-admin ?

Comment: use the `!is_admin()` conditional at your will.